# Auto-appending URL parameters when using a custom hx-push-url value

Tags: htmx

I would like to push a custom URL but keep the parameters of the original request. Consider the following example

```html
<script 
 src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.7.0" 
 integrity="sha384-EzBXYPt0/T6gxNp0nuPtLkmRpmDBbjg6WmCUZRLXBBwYYmwAUxzlSGej0ARHX0Bo" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<select id="select-number" name="number" hx-get="/debug" hx-push-url="/debug2" hx-target="#target">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

Let's say I serve this at `http://127.0.0.1:7000/debug`. If I  select `2` in the select field this will trigger a request to `/debug?number=2` as expected. However, the URL pushed to the browser is `http://127.0.0.1:7000/debug2`, **not** including the parameters.

I want the following pushed to the history: `http://127.0.0.1:7000/debug2?number=2`

This has also been discussed in [htmx issue #653](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/653). From my understanding what I'm doing should work, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: As a workaround, you can try doing this server-side by adding a header to the response.  

    Response.Headers.Add("HX-Replace-Url", "/debug2?number=2)  

see <https://htmx.org/headers/hx-replace-url/>

Comment: Thanks @Mueller-Nico I tried to work around this using `htmx:xhr:loadend` and changing the `htmx-internal-data` keys there, but that didn't work out, so I eventually used [xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook) to conditionally change the `response.finalURL` value. Super ugly of course.

Answer (score 1):

See if `hx-push-url="true"` would work for you, [documented here](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-push-url/):

```html
<input
  name="query"
  hx-get="/search"
  hx-trigger="keyup change delay:200ms"
  hx-push-url="true"
/>
```

Comment: The point of my question is that I want a custom URL to be pushed. The third point in the linked documentation.

Comment: Is see, sorry for misreading the question!